# Differential Amplifier circuit

Tags: amplifier, differential, single-ended

I wanted to transform a differential signal to a single-ended signal using a differential amplifier. When I am reading the datasheets for fully differential amplifiers there are just single-ended/differential to differential cases shown.

Is this possible with fully differential amplifiers?

Comment: Why do you want to use a differential amplifier? Normally you use a differential amplifier when you want a differential output.

Comment: Oh okay, then this is my fault :D. So I just need a normal opamp I guess?

Comment: I would think so. There are a number of op-amp topologies you could use depending on your exact needs.

Comment: Also search for instrumentation amplifier, or differential line driver / differential line receiver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want something with a differential front end.  Look up things called *instrumentation amplifiers*.  That's a whole class of amplifier, which does differential to single-ended conversion.

You can also make a differential amplifier with a ordinary opamp, although the specs won't be as good as what you can get with instrumentation amplifiers.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for may be an **instrumentation amplifier** (as just pointed out).

An instrumentation amplifier is a differential op-amp circuit providing high input impedances with ease of gain adjustment through the variation of a single resistor.

[image: Typical instrumentation amplifier schematic]

This circuit is constructed from a buffered differential amplifier stage with three new resistors linking the two buffer circuits together.

You can change the differential gain of the instrumentation amplifier simply by changing the value of one resistor: `Rgain`